# How to use custom config file for SparkSession (without using spark-submit to submit application)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an independent python script that creates a `SparkSession` by invoking the following lines of code and I can see that it configures the spark session perfectly as mentioned in the `spark-defaults.conf` file.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Tester").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

If I want to pass as a parameter, another file that contains spark configuration that I want to be used instead of the `spark-default.conf`, how can I specify this while creating a `SparkSession`?

I can see that I can pass a `SparkConf` object but is there a way to create one automatically from a file containing all the configurations?

Do I have to manually parse the input file and set the appropriate configuration manually?

Comment: You can use the [`--properties-file` flag during the submit](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-properties.html) to specify a different file, but note that [any properties specified with the `SparkConf` will override the properties file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties).

Comment: I dont really use spark submit and run this just as a python script since I create the spark context manually myself so I cant use the --properties-file option. I dont seem to be able to just pass my existing code to the spark-submit and get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use `spark-submit` your best here is overriding `SPARK_CONF_DIR`. Create separate directory for each configurations set:

```
$ configs tree           
.
├── conf1
│   ├── docker.properties
│   ├── fairscheduler.xml
│   ├── log4j.properties
│   ├── metrics.properties
│   ├── spark-defaults.conf
│   ├── spark-defaults.conf.template
│   └── spark-env.sh
└── conf2
    ├── docker.properties
    ├── fairscheduler.xml
    ├── log4j.properties
    ├── metrics.properties
    ├── spark-defaults.conf
    ├── spark-defaults.conf.template
    └── spark-env.sh
```

And set environment variable before you initialize any JVM dependent objects:

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ["SPARK_CONF_DIR"] = "/path/to/configs/conf1"
spark  = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

or

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ["SPARK_CONF_DIR"] = "/path/to/configs/conf2"
spark  = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

This is workaround and might not work in complex scenarios.